# Toggle class on trigger and on its associated text (sibling)

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to create my own multiselect dropdown with checkboxes. Works so fine, so far, the only problem that I have is, that the class `.checkbox-selected` which triggers the design of the checkbox rectangle, is only triggered when I click on the checkbox, but not on the text which is to the right of it, or the link in general.

How can I achieved it, that the trigger is also set by clicking the link or text?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".dropdown-items .checkbox").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("checkbox-selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-items {
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
}

.checkbox-selected {
  background-color: #BC9590;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-color: #bc9590;
  background-image: url(../img/checked.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
  <div class="checkbox"></div>
  <p>demo</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
  <div class="checkbox"></div>
  <p>demo</p>
</a>
```

---

**UPDATE:** (*with multiple dropdowns*)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger-dropdown').on('click', function() {
    $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').toggleClass('filter-dropdown-active');
    return false;
  });
});

$(document).click(function() {
  if ($('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').hasClass('filter-dropdown-active')) {
    $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').toggleClass('filter-dropdown-active');
  }
});

$('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

/* Triggers Checkbox Icon for Dropdowns */

$(".dropdown-items").click(function() {
  $(this).find('.checkbox').toggleClass("checkbox-selected");
});
```

```css
.sidebar-filter-wrapper {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.filter-label {
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color ease 250ms;
}

.filter-label:hover {
  background-color: rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.20);
  color: #303030;
}

.filter-label img {
  margin-left: .625rem;
}

.filter-dropdown-wrapper {
  margin-top: .625rem;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem, ;
  left: 0;
}

.filter-dropdown-active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-items {
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-items:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
}

.checkbox-selected {
  background-color: #BC9590;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-color: #bc9590;
  background-image: url(../img/checked.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar-filter-wrapper">
  <div class="filter-pill-wrapper">
    <div class="filter-dropdown">
      <a class="filter-label trigger-dropdown">
          Marken vor Ort
          <img src="img/toggle.svg">
      </a>
      <div class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Skinceuticals</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Babor</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Eucerin</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Hermés</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Kérastase</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Clinique</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-pill-wrapper">
    <div class="filter-dropdown">
      <a class="filter-label trigger-dropdown">
          Marken vor Ort
          <img src="img/toggle.svg">
      </a>
      <div class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Skinceuticals</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Babor</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Eucerin</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Hermés</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Kérastase</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Clinique</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to bind the event listener to the containing anchor tag and select the `.checkbox` in the handler with `find()`:

```js
$(".dropdown-items").click(function() {
  $(this).find('.checkbox').toggleClass("checkbox-selected");
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".dropdown-items").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.checkbox').toggleClass("checkbox-selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-items {
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
}

.checkbox-selected {
  background-color: #BC9590;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-color: #bc9590;
  background-image: url(../img/checked.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
  <div class="checkbox"></div>
  <p>demo</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
  <div class="checkbox"></div>
  <p>demo</p>
</a>
```

---

(*refering to your updated question*)

**trigger-click-handler:**

You are toggling the classes of all `.filter-dropdown-wrapper`s. Instead you should select only the associated dropdown and toggle its class. To achieve this you could use `$(this)` for the clicked trigger and the `siblings()` method for finding the associated dropdown.

```js
$(this).siblings('.filter-dropdown-wrapper')
```

For closing other active dropdowns you could first save the state if the associated dropdown is active in a variable.

```js
let active_dropdown = $(this).siblings('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').hasClass('filter-dropdown-active');
```

Then you could remove the `filter-dropdown-active` class from all wrappers and add that class to the associated dropdown if it wasn't active.

**outside-dropdown-click:**

If you just toggle the active class you would also toggle that class on the closed dropdown. Therefor you should simply remove that class from all dropdowns (*no `if` necessary*).

**Working example:**

I declared all event listeners in the `$(document).ready(function() {...});` because i found no reason why only the trigger-click-listener should be inside.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.trigger-dropdown').on('click', function() {
    let active_dropdown = $(this).siblings('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').hasClass('filter-dropdown-active');
    $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').removeClass('filter-dropdown-active');
    if (!active_dropdown) {
      $(this).siblings('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').addClass('filter-dropdown-active');
    }
    return false;
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').removeClass('filter-dropdown-active');
  });

  $('.filter-dropdown-wrapper').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(".dropdown-items").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.checkbox').toggleClass("checkbox-selected");
  });

});
```

```css
.sidebar-filter-wrapper {
  padding-top: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.filter-label {
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color ease 250ms;
}

.filter-label:hover {
  background-color: rgba(226, 226, 226, 0.20);
  color: #303030;
}

.filter-label img {
  margin-left: .625rem;
}

.filter-dropdown-wrapper {
  margin-top: .625rem;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5rem, ;
  left: 0;
}

.filter-dropdown-active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-items {
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown-items:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
}

.checkbox-selected {
  background-color: #BC9590;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-color: #bc9590;
  background-image: url(../img/checked.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar-filter-wrapper">
  <div class="filter-pill-wrapper">
    <div class="filter-dropdown">
      <a class="filter-label trigger-dropdown">
          Marken vor Ort
          <img src="img/toggle.svg">
      </a>
      <div class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Skinceuticals</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Babor</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Eucerin</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Hermés</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Kérastase</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Clinique</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-pill-wrapper">
    <div class="filter-dropdown">
      <a class="filter-label trigger-dropdown">
          Marken vor Ort
          <img src="img/toggle.svg">
      </a>
      <div class="filter-dropdown-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Skinceuticals</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Babor</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Eucerin</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Hermés</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Kérastase</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-items">
          <div class="checkbox"></div>
          <p>Clinique</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed something at the code, so that the dropdown is now closing when someone clicks outside of the wrapper and it keeps it there when the click is inside the wrapper. Problem is that the $(this).find function doesn't work anymore. It opens again, all classes. Where is the mistake? I updated the file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. When i add the event listener to your updated Javascript it works as expected. By the way you shouldn't overwrite the original stack snippet because it is necessary for future visitors to understand the question. Therefor i rolled your edit back and pasted the new code in an extra snippet...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Basically, I have now built the dropdown and use it in several places. In the dropdown I have the checkboxes where you have already helped me. I have now tried to apply the solution approach of you to the dropdowns, so that not every main element is opened if it has the same class. Only the approach you mentioned doesn't seem to work here. 

https://jsfiddle.net/cLt5aqx3/

Comment: fixed the jsfiddle. Sorry. https://jsfiddle.net/397Lzvj5/